# laravel redirect::back() redirects to favicon

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel

I have an app using laravel 4.1. In an edit function - which has been working fine up until now has started to attampts to redirect back to favicon instead of the submitting page and throws an httpexception error.

favicon is being stored in the referrer url session variable for some reason.

On submitting a form to the controller method if there are validation errors it should redirect to the form. The forms URL is `http://downscms.loc/articles/300/edit`

it submits to the edit method in controller and should redirect using this code:

```
return Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
```

I'm positive this has been working in the past - I did a composer update over the weekend.

This happens in Chrome and Firefox

This is on my testing server which is apache.

On my testing server the favicons do not appear - but I've not had any problems in the past.

Removing the favicon.ico file from the public directory stops the error - but not a correct fix

Is this a Laravel issue or an apache issue and how do I resolve?

my .htaccess file on my local server is the unmodified laravel file

ANy help appreciated to get to the bottom of this

Comment: Same issue here! And I'm not using apache but nginx and PHP 5.4 build-in server.

Comment: I prefer not to user `back()` its better to specify the url or route to the edit form.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a weird problem and this may not be your solution, bet let's give it a go;

When you request a page, your browser automatically tries to fetch the favicon of the domain. If it doesn't exist (or you misconfigured your .htaccess), then your .htaccess sends the request of to Laravel which will show a 404.

Maybe, Laravel sets the last URL to be the one to the icon during the invisible favicon.ico request. When you then go 'back', it is the last URL your browser requested.

Once again, I could be totally off, but try adding a favicon.ico to the root of your domain and see if that works.

Comment: This happens on pretty much every framework with a front controller, so I wouldn't be surprised if this was the case here if Laravel logs requests in order to know what `back()` should do.